# How to load an image from low to high resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how is it possible! Load and image from low to high resolution using web client languagens (CSS, JS).

I've been looking at [Medium](https://medium.com/@lekker/laravel-query-builder-outside-of-laravel-eb5ac3e19be2)

This is the low resolution

[image: Low resolution]

This is the high resolution
[image: High resolution]

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/dombrant/blurry-image-load here's a image loading library based on Medium

Comment: OMG. That's it. Thanks @dantheman93

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use some JS solution for this, as suggested by dantheman93, check out [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/) article on how to recreate it manually, or you could just check out [progressive JPGs](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-a-progressive-jpeg/), as it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I like the idea to create it manually. It helps undestanding what's happening behind there! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

So how does it work?

Well you need 2 images. 1 with super low quality and your normal image.

You set the low quality on `src` and lazy load the other image.

Thats all the magic behind it.

Initialy you set `filter: blur(5px)` on the image and when its done with loading the high quality image you unset the blurr.

A good library for lazyload is the https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload

Note here: You need to throttle the network speed. You can do it with google chrome by pressing F12, go to `Network` ans select `Slow 3G` then start the code snippet

The image gets cached so it loads out of the cache. you will need to clear the cache before you run the snippet to see the transition.

```js
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
  callback_loaded: (el) => {
     el.style.setProperty("filter", "none")
  }
});
```

```css
img {
   filter: blur(5px);
   transition: filter 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@17.1.0/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>

<img class="lazy" src="https://blogxon.com/5f1492591d873e4284aacdce/thumbnails/placeholder/1597094737252.jpeg" data-src="https://blogxon.com/5f1492591d873e4284aacdce/thumbnails/1597094737252.jpeg" />
```